# Out Of memory error using Universal Image Loader and images getting refreshed

Tags: android, android-listview, universal-image-loader

I am using the universal image loader to display the images as thumbnail in ListView however i am getting the out of memory error and when i scroll the list than the new view is having the images of first view when the list was not on scroll stage but than the images gets set to proper image which it should be.

```
public class NewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<String> movieThumbnail;
    private ArrayList<String> movieText;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    static File cacheDir;

    ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(activity)
    .memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
    .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
    .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
    .threadPoolSize(5)
    .imageDownloader(new URLConnectionImageDownloader(120 * 1000, 120 * 1000))
    .enableLogging()
    .build();

    DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheOnDisc()
    .cacheInMemory()
    .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
    .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
    .build();

    private ImageLoader imageLoader= ImageLoader.getInstance();

    public NewAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<String> movieThumbnail, ArrayList<String> movieText) {
        activity = a;
        /*data=d;*/
        this.movieThumbnail = movieThumbnail;
        this.movieText = movieText;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"JunkFolder");
        else
            cacheDir=activity.getCacheDir();
        if(!cacheDir.exists())
            cacheDir.mkdirs();

        imageLoader.init(config);

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return movieText.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
              vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, null);

        TextView text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.rowListTextView);
        ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.movieImage);
        text.setText(movieText.get(position));
        imageLoader.displayImage(movieThumbnail.get(position), image, options);
        return vi;
    }
}
```

and here is Xml Layout for ImageView and TextView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_relativelayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/latest_list_toggle" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/movieImage"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rowListTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/movieImage"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="21dp"
        android:paddingTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="17sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I solved the problem of setting the proper image on listView refresh. Earlier I was not passing the variable of DisplayImageOption while calling the Imageloader.displayImage(). Now its working proper. :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `.resetViewBeforeLoading()` in DisplayImageOptions.

Comment: I'm loading an image with base adapter in which i'm set the image in inflater imageview with picasso and also try with image loader too, but while loading image in place holder i'm getting out of memory exception with universal image loader and with picasso in particular samsung s4 device
i also use the latest picasso jar but getting nothing for solution

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/623

i already try large hip = true and bitmap.recycle but can't resolve it

Answer (score 4):

try next (all of them or several):

Reduce thread pool size in configuration (.threadPoolSize(...)). 1 - 5 is recommended.
Use

```
 .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
```

in display options. Bitmaps in RGB_565 consume 2 times less memory than in ARGB_8888.
Use

```
.memoryCache(new WeakMemoryCache())
```

in configuration or disable caching in memory at all 
in display options (don't call .cacheInMemory()).
Use

```
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
```

in display options. Or try

```
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY).
```

Avoid using RoundedBitmapDisplayer. It creates new Bitmap object with ARGB_8888 config for displaying during work.

Answer (score 1):

make sure you make Image size as require in Your ImageLoader

```
// decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }
```