# How to use "Android-Universal-Image-Loader"

Tags: android, listview, gridview

I want to gridview and listview using Android-Universal-Image-Loader.

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

I downloaded and modified it.

it works fine, however when I change and move the source to another project, it's crashed.

I don't know why :(

there is no error and any error messages.

I think it's null point error or initiate library.

I think error will comes with this part.

```
    listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    ((GridView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
```

and

```
    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.v("OWL","TEST1");
        return imageUrls.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        Log.v("OWL","TEST2");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Log.v("OWL","TEST3");
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.v("OWL","TEST4");
        final ImageView imageView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
            Log.v("OWL","TEST5");
        } else {
            imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            Log.v("OWL","TEST6");
        }

        imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);
        Log.v("OWL","TEST7");
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

I cannot see TEST6, TEST7 on the LOGCAT

I attached log blow. please help me or let't me know how to use that library.

```
03-25 18:24:17.208: D/AndroidRuntime(312): Shutting down VM
03-25 18:24:17.208: W/dalvikvm(312): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41693438)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.checkConfiguration(ImageLoader.java:359)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.displayImage(ImageLoader.java:200)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader.displayImage(ImageLoader.java:162)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at com.kmob.camera.ImageGridActivity$ImageAdapter.getView(ImageGridActivity.java:117)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2449)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1030)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15364)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:617)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:399)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15364)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15364)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1396)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15364)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4824)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2359)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15364)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1974)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1217)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1390)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1110)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4472)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: `03-25 18:24:17.228: E/AndroidRuntime(312): java.lang.IllegalStateException: ImageLoader must be init with configuration before using`. Learn to read logcat. You havent init configuration for your loader. Use Kroger's answer and remove parts you don't need.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Did you resolve this problem? You need to initialize the imageLoader with the example code on the UniversalImageLoader:

```
File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getCacheDirectory(context);
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context)
        .memoryCacheExtraOptions(480, 800) // default = device screen dimensions
        .discCacheExtraOptions(480, 800, CompressFormat.JPEG, 75)
        .taskExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
        .taskExecutorForCachedImages(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR)
        .threadPoolSize(3) // default
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1) // default
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO) // default
        .denyCacheImageMultipleSizesInMemory()
        .memoryCache(new UsingFreqLimitedMemoryCache(2 * 1024 * 1024)) // default
        .memoryCacheSize(2 * 1024 * 1024)
        .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // default
        .discCacheSize(50 * 1024 * 1024)
        .discCacheFileCount(100)
        .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator()) // default
        .imageDownloader(new BaseImageDownloader(context)) // default
        .defaultDisplayImageOptions(DisplayImageOptions.createSimple()) // default
        .enableLogging()
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks. the sample project initialize the imageLoader at the Manifest file!!!!! I didn't know that :(

Comment: What do you mean initialize the imageLoader in the Manifest file?

Comment: @Kgrover the AndroidManifest.xml of sample app has android:name=".UILApplication"

Answer (score 1):

It looks like wherever you create your `imageLoader`, you need to call `imageLoader.init(someConfigObject);`

`someConfigObject` is of type `ImageLoaderConfiguration`

Answer (score 0):

## Use this Simple Code Is Working

init ImageLoader into yor adapter class

```
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(ctx));
```

Then use this below code into place on set image it will working...

```
DisplayImageOptions options=new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.stories_holder_sq)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.stories_holder_sq)
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.stories_holder_sq)
                .build();
        imageLoader.displayImage(naturalDashBoardBean.getImgUrl(), categoryViewHolder.categoryItemImg, options);
```

Comment: if u need more info about universal imageloader and load easy way and also cache the image view to try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40154744/6477998